# How to run a mysqldump from a .txt or .sql file inside a command line window?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

If I run the follow line directly in command line window it will works good.

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -u root d3bi>C:\Users\me\Desktop\test\testDump.sql
```

How can I run a .txt or .sql file named testDump.txt or testDump.sql from my cmd line window?
Inside this file we will have the same line:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqldump -u root d3bi>C:\Users\me\Desktop\test\testDump.sql
```

Comment: Well, your question is pretty unclear. Do you want to run you mysqldump line inside a batch script ?

Comment: Hi, I want to copy my mysqldump statemet and past inside a .txt file or .sql file. And I'd like to call this .txt file from command line. Not .bat.

Comment: You can call the file what you like (the extension just changes the icon and on_double_click behaviour). Do you want to run this .txt file through the mysql client?

Comment: Yes, the goal is to run a routine of 15 databases dump. I could write all 15 mysqldump commands inside a command window. But I was trying to call 1 file that will call each line for each database. I am avoid to use .bat. But if there is no solution, I will create a batch file.

Comment: A batch file seems to be the best solution (or a Powershell script). Why do you want to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commandline mysql allows `\!` to do what you want, but you appear to be in Windows, which does not really allow for such a feature.

So, No, you can't do it.

For reading INSERT statements (etc) back in there is the `source` command.

Can you turn things inside out?  You can get a list of databases, or otherwise create MySQL commands, from

```
mysql ... -e "statement..."
```

and you redirect that to a .bat file, which could then be executed.

It seems like you need a .bat file.